# Battery of my Mac with Problems

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

When I charge my MacBook the battery goes only up to 99% and doesn't reach 100%. Is this something to worry about and if yes, how do I fix it?

Comment: how OLD is your Battery on your Mac?

Comment: well 
my mac is mid 2012, so the battery has the same time.

Comment: Does it show "service" or "Replace" battery when you click on the icon.

Comment: Please stick to one question per post. I've removed your second question, feel free to ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the Battery status open About this Mac -More -System

now look for battery information in there under Power.

Look for:

Charge cycles count < 600 for yours

and the Full Charge Capacity (mAh): > 4557

In any case [resetting your SMC](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) (System Management Controller will help some).

Comment: The information of my mac is this:


http://i.imgur.com/boqe3rw.png


Above the red line are the charge cycles count and

Above the green line is the Full Charge Capacity

So how to restarted the smc?; Please give me the link

Comment: That looks like a solid battery. Did you reset the SMC?

Comment: added link to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I do it.
However the problem persists